# Rails hide controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

i have `match ":id" => "people#show"` in my routes.rb
now i can access `http://localhost:3000/1`

but,in views <%= link_to 'Show', people %> it will generate `http://localhost:3000/people/1` ,

i want to it to be `http://localhost:3000/1`

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this to ensure that only numeric ids are matched:

```
match '/:id' => 'people#show', :constraints => {:id => /\d+/}
```

A good alternative might be to use some kind of identifier, even if it's not the controller name: http://localhost:3000/p/1. This will at least ensure that if you add other controllers and actions you don't end up having to change your routing structure.

Comment: got an error - Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements: /^\d/

Comment: I fixed the regular expression. By default route constraints are anchored, so you don't need the ^ character.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom route to match that in config/routes.rb. At the bottom of your routes.rb file you will have a route like match `':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` 
or something like `resources :people`. You might have to write a route that matches the route type you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a named route.

```
match ':id' => 'people#show', :as => :person
```

And fix your views to use your new method `person_path(user_id)`.